# How to call a server side script with extjs and let the user download the text response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, perl, extjs

I want to call a perl script on a server when the user clicks on a extjs toolbar button. The download dialog should open automaticaly after the click.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Ext.Ajax](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.Ajax):

```
yourButton.on('click', function(btn, e) {
  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'your_script.pl',
    params: {
        param1: 'The first param',
        param2: 'The second param',
    },
    success: function(response) {
        var text = response.responseText;
        // process server response here. For example
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This won't work, the file contents will end up in the responseText variable.

Comment: I was searching for a way to make my extjs-clientside-code call a php-script on the serverside and get a response from that script. This made the trick.

Answer (score 1):

An Ajax request does not work to make appear a download dialog in a browser, you need to redirect the user to an URL where your server's response has properly **Content-type** and a **Content-disposition** HTTP headers.

You can make the *trick* with ExtJS submitting a hidden form after the click or providing a direct link instead of a Button in the toolbar.

Comment: +1. You are right. I was not. I hadn't understand that it was all about simple file downloading from server.